# How to do max-depth search in ack and grep?

Tags: grep, ack

Is there any way to tell `ack` to only search for text on the current folder? (or specify a `max-depth` level?) And with `grep`?

Comment: No, ack does not have a max-depth option, other than the `-n` to not recurse at all.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `-n` for `no-recurse`:

```
$ ack -n foo
```

`grep` is not recursive by default, and you should use the `-r` flag only if you want a recursive search.

You can search the current directory with `grep` as follows:

```
$ grep -- foo *
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question? (what if I want to recurse to a depth of 2)

Comment: Good point, I missed that. Any suggestions?

Comment: @StevenLu, you can recurse a number of directories by using globs: `ack -n pattern */*/`. It has several caveats, like expanding directories with an extreme number of subdirectories. If you make sure that the glob has a slash at the end, then it will only expand directory names, so that should limit the potential for damage, a bit.

Comment: Cool. FWIW I don't use ack anymore, ripgrep is where it's at.

Comment: where can I find clarification for the syntax 'grep --'? I didn't find it it 'man grep'.

Comment: @user3804598 it's not a `grep` thing, it's a shell thing. From `man bash`: "A -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and arguments."

Answer (score 58):

You can couple find with the `-exec` argument. Example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec grep foo {} \;
```

This can be scaled, i.e. `-maxdepth 2`.

**Edit**

As mentioned in the [answer by @Stéphane Chazelas], it is advisable to restrict `find` to regular files so that `grep` doesn't produce an error when the argument `{}` actually is a directory path:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -H foo {} \;
```

- `-type f` is a filter for `find` that limits the search results to files
- `-H` is a `grep` option used to print a filename for every match (desired behavior when more than one file match)

Comment: Stephane, my answer (`-maxdepth 1`) was scaleable.  For example `-maxdepth 2`.  I do not know how to describe the edit you made as such.

Comment: it will not reach @stephane if you don't use the @.

Comment: Yes sorry, I agree my edit was too much intrusive. You may still want to clarify that that (`-maxdepth`) is not portable/standard syntax (only GNU and some BSDs). Also, there's no point using `\;` here (run one `grep` per file). Use `grep -H foo {} +` (GNU specific) or `grep foo /dev/null {} +` (standard) to make sure the file name is always printed. The standard equivalent to `-maxdepth 2` would be `find . -path './*/*' -type d -prune -o -type f -exec ...`

Comment: Also note that yours will give error messages for directories (including `.` as you don't give the `-mindepth 1`) while GNU `grep` will not try to read directories with `-r` (it _recurses_ on them). You may want to add a `-d skip` to `grep` (assuming GNU grep) or better add `! -type d` to `find` or even better `-type f` (or `-xtype f` assuming GNU `find`) as you probably don't want `grep` to read non-regular files.

Comment: I tend to use `grep -Hin` with this approach so that I can see the filename and the line that the occurrence is on.

Comment: VAT DA FAAK?!? Make grep a --max-depth parameter!

Comment: @uav feel free to send a patch to the GNU utils mailing list. The idea behind GNU tools is that each tool should have a limited, specialized set of features and be used in cooperation. GNU `find` has all the features you need to drill down a file system, filtering out anything you don't want. Embedding it within grep, sed and gawk seems like a lot of redundant effort.

Answer (score 2):

For an equivalent of GNU `grep -r foo .` that looks only in regular files in the current directory and not any of the subdirectories, you can do:

- `zsh` and GNU `grep` or compatible:

  ```
  grep -H foo ./*(.D)
  ```
- standard `find` and `grep` from any shell:

  ```
  find . ! -name . -prune -type f -exec grep foo /dev/null {} +
  ```
- GNU `find` and GNU `grep` (or compatible) from any shell:

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -H foo {} +
  ```

To look for files at depths 1 to 3 (in `./file`, `./subdir/file`, `./subdir/subsubdir/file`, but not any deeper):

- GNU `find` and GNU `grep` (or compatible) from any shell:

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -exec grep -H foo {} +
  ```
- standard `find` and `grep`, but assuming file names are valid text in the locale:

  ```
  find . '(' ! -path './*/*/*' -o -prune ')' -o -exec grep foo /dev/null {} +
  ```
- `zsh` and GNU `grep` or compatible:

  ```
  set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
  grep -H foo ./**/*~./*/*/*/*(D.)
  ```

  though note that it's inefficient as it still looks for files at any depth before excluding them with the `~` extendedglob operator.

`-H` (GNU extension) / `/dev/null` is to make sure `grep` prints the name of the file even if only  one file is given to it.

`-type f` or `zsh`'s `.` glob qualifier is to select only *regular* files (like GNU `grep` does by default with `-r` nowadays), to the exclusion of all other types of files such as symlinks (even if they point to regular files), directories, fifos, devices...

Answer (score 1):

I'm obviously late to the topic, but this may prove useful to a future reader. After reading the comments and answers above, perhaps a wrapper script for grep is in order until GNU find gains a -maxdepth option. Using a pattern like the following,

```
 grep -Hin foo `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`
```

the following script will effectively wrap the pair of commands:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# USAGE: grep-maxdepth <NUM> <GREP_ARGS>
#
#    <NUM>        integer specifying the maxdepth passed to find
#    <GREP_ARGS>  arguments provided to grep
#
depth=$1
shift
# DON'T DO THIS ! grep $* `find . -maxdepth ${depth} -type f`
# DO this based upon comments
find . -maxdepth ${depth} -type f -exec grep $* {} \;
```

This solution should work regardless of the availability of GNU grep; however, the usage of `-maxdepth` for `find` implies the installation of GNU's Tools.

I don't use `ack`, but this simple solution should work for it as well.

*NOTE: Trivially-edited based upon comment from Stéphane Chazelas. This should now properly-accommodate white space and other characters in file names. Thanks.*

Comment: That's wrong for a number of reasons. See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697) and [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) for instance.